# How to xpath selected text in the dropdown

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

```
**HTML Code**
  <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-4 col-sm-4" for="type-select">Category<span style="color:red">*</span></label>
        <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8">
            <select defaultattr="4" class="form-control input-style mandatory" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field CategoryID must be a number." id="CategoryID" name="CategoryID"><option value="">--Select--</option>
<option value="1">Architectural Firm</option>
<option value="2">Interior Design Firm</option>
<option value="3">General Contractor</option>
<option selected="selected" value="4">2tec2 Sales Network</option>
<option value="5">Cleaning Company</option>
<option value="6">Commercial end user</option>
<option value="7">Distribution company</option>
<option value="8">Hotel Company</option>
</select>
```

I Want the xpath to get the selected value(here it is 4th option in above code).

Comment: show us html text code of dropdown

Comment: You can use Select Class  to get Drop-Down value

Comment: <select defaultattr="4" class="form-control input-style mandatory" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field CategoryID must be a number." id="CategoryID" name="CategoryID"><option value="">--Select--</option>  
<option value="1">Architectural Firm</option>  
<option value="2">Interior Design Firm</option>  
<option value="3">General Contractor</option>    
<option selected="selected" value="4">2tec2 Sales Network</option>  
<option value="5">Cleaning Company</option>  
<option value="6">Commercial end user</option>  
</select>

Comment: @Ankur Singh - How can i use SelectClass in xpath

Comment: @Bhuvana Update your question with elaborating information, by adding HTML in Question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the xpath to get the selected option of a drop down?

Try this xpath: `//select[@id='CategoryID']//option[@selected='selected']`

You get the text of the selected text using GetText()

```
String text = driver.findElement(By.xpath(...)).getText();
```

Comment: This is very helpfull. But this is not what exactly i need.Above i have posted the html code for one dropdown field.There are similar 5 dropdowns and i need to get the selected text in each dropdown and store it in an array

Answer (score 1):

Addition to Shn's answer and to your comment on it. 
If you need to get values from 5 similar dropdowns why dont you run the given xpath statement by Shn 5 times for each dropdown(by changing the id in xpath)and save all of them in an array

```
String textA = driver.findElement(By.xpath(...)).getText();
String textB = driver.findElement(By.xpath(...)).getText();
String textC = driver.findElement(By.xpath(...)).getText();
String textD = driver.findElement(By.xpath(...)).getText();
String textE = driver.findElement(By.xpath(...)).getText();

String array[] = new String[] { textA, textB, textC, textD, textE };
```

you can also use a loop for this.